# How to generate accumulated inventory plot based on week number in Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, plot, inventory-management

I would like to draw automatically accumulated inventory plot using Excel VBA 2016.

I have inventory data for different year in the format of "20XXYY". Here "XX" indicates year and "YY" indicates week number in a year (1 to 52). I will have data similar to picture 1. Then I would like to sort it as picture 2. Finally draw plot as picture 3. However, I would like to have it automatically using VBA.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

[image: Picture 3]

My question is that how can I create sequential YearWeek column automatically for the plot?

I have used "=SUM($Y$2:Y2)"^^ formula in "Accumulated Inventory" column. I will highly appreciate if I will get any clue.

Comment: You mean you want the chart to update as you add rows to your data? If so, you don't need VBA for this. Just create a excel table and have the table name be the chart source. It will update as you add values

Comment: @urdearboy My question was how can I generate automatically  201948, 201949, 201950, 201951,201952, 202001, 202002 instead of 201948, 201949, 202001, 202002 cloumn? As I have to generate accumulated inventory plot.  Please check third image.

Comment: You want to automatically generate the numbers in the YearWeek column so the year bumps up when the last two digits reach 52?

Comment: `=YEAR(A1)&TEXT(WEEKNUM(A1),"00")`

Comment: @Michal Rosa and user3099345, For example if I have 201948 and 202011 then I want to create 16 consecutive cell values automatically by VBA e.g. 201948, 201949, 201950, 201951,201952, 202001, 202002......202011. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'This is the answer. I have figure it out. Thanks for your support.

```
Sub consecutiveNumber()

Dim wsFrom As Worksheet
Dim Com As String
Dim lLastNumber,FirstNumber, l, i As Long


'change to names of sheets you are coptying from and to

Set wsFrom = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")


'Get the value in the last and first used text box of column A

lLastNumber = wsFrom.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value
FirstNumber = wsFrom.Range("A1").Value
'clear column B

wsFrom.Range("B:B").Clear

'Initializing the cell index value
i = 1
'fill column B on sheet 1 with first to last number on column A

 For l = FirstNumber To lLastNumber

'Converting number to string
Com = Right(CStr(l), 2)

If CInt(Com) >= 53 Then
l = l + 48

    wsFrom.Range("M" & i) = l
    i = i + 1
 Else

    wsFrom.Range("M" & i) = l
    i = i + 1

  End If


Next

End Sub
```